# Why update() method from MutableStateFlow doesn't seem to work?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I'm actually creating a `MutableStateFlow` from a data class in this way

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(DataUiState())
val uiState: StateFlow<DataUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

When calling in this from:

```
val newsItems = repository.dataItems(item)
_uiState.update {
    it.copy(dataItems = dataItems)
}
```

the method `update {}` shows a non-exist method error in compiler, why is this happening?

Comment: Didn't you mean `it.copy(dataItems = newsItems)`? Although, I don't think it has anything to do with the error.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Joffrey I'm getting Unresolved reference: update error –

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you import this function? It's an extension function, not a member. So if you didn't use star imports, chances are you haven't imported it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the function `update` to use it:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update

...

val newsItems = repository.dataItems(item)
_uiState.update {
    it.copy(dataItems = newsItems)
}
```

Also make sure to import `kotlinx-coroutines-core` library:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0'
```